# Problem with pagination, at one point i got lost

Tags: reactjs

I'm tryng to paginate the pages of [rickandmortyapi.com](https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/#info-and-pagination) but I'm having problems.

I'm call the api with axios:

```js
// get all characters
export const getCharacters = async () => {
  let response = await Axios.get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/`)

  return response.data
}
```

With this request, I can map and show the characters.

To paginate, I created a component called Pagination, but I'm having problems to change the response of getCharacters function and insert ?page=2 at the end of the endpoint.

Pagination Component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getCharacters } from '../../API'

const Pagination = () => {
  // use state to keep track of the current page
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState([])
  // use effect to fetch the characters
  useEffect(() => {
    // async function
    async function getPages() {
      const responsePages = await getCharacters()
      setPagination(responsePages)
      return responsePages
    }
    // call the function
    getPages()
  }, [])
  console.log(pagination)

  return (
    // pagination
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          // I dont know what to do with this
        }}
      >
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Pagination
```

Updade:

I did another api call:

```js
// paginate characters
export const getCharactersPaginated = async (page) => {
  let response = await Axios.get(
    `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=${page}`
  )
  return response.data
}
```

I'm lost on how to use this in my Pagination component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Pagination = ({ setCharacters, setIsLoading }) => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(1)

  const fetchCharacters = async (pageNumber) => {
    setIsLoading(true)

    let baseUrl = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character'

    if (pageNumber) {
      baseUrl += `/?page=${pageNumber}`
    }

    const result = await axios(baseUrl)

    const pageInfo = result.data.info

    setInfo({
      next: pageNumber < pageInfo.pages ? pageNumber + 1 : null,
      current: pageNumber,
      prev: pageNumber > 1 ? pageNumber - 1 : null,
    })
    setCharacters(result.data.results)
    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCharacters(1)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='pagination'>
      {info.prev ? (
        <button type='button' onClick={() => fetchCharacters(info.prev)}>
          {info.prev}
        </button>
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment />
      )}

      <button type='button'>{info.current}</button>

      {info.next ? (
        <button type='button' onClick={() => fetchCharacters(info.next)}>
          {info.next}
        </button>
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Pagination
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const getCharacters = async (page = 1) => {
  let response = await Axios.get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=${page}`)

  return response.data
}
```

```js
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1); 
  useEffect(() => {
  const responsePages = await getCharacters(page); 
  setPagination(responsePages); 
}, [currentPage]);
```

you can change the current Page onClick.

Handle some edge cases as well.